# is this Asbestos? or anything dangerous?

Tags: water, insulation, pipe, asbestos

[image][image]In my garage there are some water pipes I believe that have a wrap around them and in some places its expanded and opened. Now I am worried if its asbestos. Its yellow and looks puffy. I near a water pipe i use for gardening. What should I do?

Thank you.[image]

Comment: At a guess, that looks like glass fibre or rock wool... But get someone to check - working from a picture is no guarantee...

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen asbestos wrapped pipes that look like that before. In my experience asbestos typically is a little more like a "plaster wrap". I would agree with the others who said that if you really need to know get it checked, but from the images it looks to be fiberglass or rock wool. Test kits aren't terribly expensive nor difficult - if you are truly worried run the test.